# Labeled grid desktop wallpaper?

Tags: desktop-customization, screen-sharing, grid

**Summary:**

I'd like a desktop wallpaper that:

- is a grid
- has cells that are each and all labeled with ascending numbers (across) and letters (down), such that the top-left cell is A0
- is larger than the width and height of my largest display (1920 for me)

**Details:**

When I'm sharing my screen with a remote audience, their screen viewer sometimes isn't able to view my entire desktop at once. Sometimes, the audience isn't savvy enough to coordinate resolutions. I want a way to quickly discover what of my screen their desktop viewer is currently displaying.

If I had a grid wallpaper like what I've described above, I could simply show my desktop when there's confusion about what of my screen they're viewing, exactly. I'd ask them to identify the cells at the boundaries of what they could see, and I could take the appropriate steps to cater to (or change, if necessary) that viewport.

This would be a simple, objective measurement that's easy to communicate, regardless of what is being showcased during the desktop sharing session.

Does a grid image like this exist anywhere online already, or is there a tool that makes generating these easy?

Comment: Not that is out there. But you can make one in Windows Pain, or Gimp, Photoshop.. Just the way you like it. But its likley not to do what you want as it will either get scaled on the remote pc.. or removed for performance...

Comment: Just use a better remote sharing software?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply send the user to a website and use the javascript below

```
<script language="text/javascript">
function getres(){
alert("Your current screen resolution is "+screen.width+" by "+screen.height+".")
}
</script>
```

then include a button on the page as follows:

```
<button type="button" onclick="getRes()">Get Resolution</button>
```